# Gitlab ci - config common Maven setting for multiple project (multiple pipeline)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

i'm new in gitlab and gitlab-ci (i'm working with github + Jenkins for several years)

with gitlab-ci and runner, i have a maven setting file (settings.xml) and i want to use it for several project. Actually I have to use " mvn install -s settings.xml" in my .gitlab-ci.yml file, (and copy settings.yml into project repository),  i dont' want to repeat that in every maven commands of all project.

After some search on internet, i create a repository (it has template gitlab-template.yml file and maven settings.xml file), the template gitlab-ci yml file define a "setup" stage to copy settings.xml file into maven repo:

```
stages:
  - setup
  
setup:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - cp ./settings.xml  $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
```

And in my project, my project gilab-ci.yml file use it as template and execute automatically setup stage.

```
include:
  - project: 'template'
    ref: 'main'  # Specify the desired branch or tag of the template repository
    file: 'java-maven/gitlab-template.yml'

stages:        
  - setup
  - deploy
```

But when i run the pipeline, the stage "setup" is OK, but the stage deploy is KO - it does not find "settings.xml" file.

The reason: gitlab runner create a virtual machine to run jobs (each vm for each different job)

- one vm for "setup" stage which copy settings.xml file to maven repo of 1rst runner
- but in "deploy" stage, we have 2nd machine which have no settings.xml

Do you have any ideals or solutions for that ?

(My final goal is use 1 settings.xml file of maven for some java project, and don't want to copy this file into all project repository then run all maven commands with option " - settings.xml")

Thank you so much guys !

(My final goal is use 1 settings.xml file of maven for some java project, and don't want to copy this file into all project repository then run all maven commands with option " - settings.xml")

Answer (score 1):

IMO the `include` statement in your pipeline code is not an adequate solution for your problem: when using `include`, Gitlab CI will insert the content of the referenced file from another project XYZ into the pipeline for your actual project ABC, but it won't use or check out any other files from that other project XYZ, thus `settings.xml` stored in XYZ's repo won't be available or known to the pipeline code running in the context of the project ABC.

What you could use instead are [project- or group-wide CI variables of the "File" type](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-file-type-cicd-variables) - e.g. you define avariable called `MAVEN_SETTINGS`, set the type to "File", provide the file content as value, and use it like this:

```yaml
maven-build:
  stage: build
  cache: []
  script:
    - mvn -s "$MAVEN_SETTINGS" clean package
```

Furthermore, if you don't want to explicitly use the `-s "$MAVEN_SETTINGS"` every time you run a Maven-based pipeline job, consider defining another group-wide variable called [`MAVEN_OPTS` or, for Maven 3.9.0+, `MAVEN_ARGS`](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html), and set its value to `-s "$MAVEN_SETTINGS"` - it would make this environment variable visible to all pipeline jobs of that group.